# Singularity of sin x / x

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Is the definition of singularity here is incomplete?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html

Take $f(x, y) = y - {\sin x\over x} = 0$.

$f_y = 1$ for all points so the condition $f_x = f_y = 0$ can never be true.

But

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableSingularity.html

says $f$ is singular when $x=0$.

Comment: It is said that the function $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},x\mapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ has an analytical continuation $\hat{f}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},x\mapsto\begin{cases}1,x=0\\f(x),x\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\end{cases}$, How does this contradict Your observation?

Comment: $f_y=1$ "for all points"...$f$ as you defined it is not defined on the line $\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or the plane $\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{C}\}$

Comment: I think the point is that a singular point of an algebraic curve and a singularity of a function on the real line or complex plane are two different concepts.

Comment: Also $f(x,y)=y-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=0$ is no polynomial equation and thus does not yield an algebraic curve

Comment: I was presuming they were the same concept, considering 'singular point' in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableSingularity.html links to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html

Comment: These are different concepts, (cf. my comment below), I agree it might be confusing the term "singular" is used in both cases

Comment: the link to [singular point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularPoint.html) in the wolfram alpha definition of [removable singularity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableSingularity.html) is (in my opinion) therefore wrong(!)

Comment: Singularity of function on the real line or complex plane is better explained e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a plane curve by the implicit equation
$$F(x,y)=0$$ where
$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}y-1,x=0\\y-\frac{\sin(x)}{x},x\neq 0\end{cases}$$
for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $F$ is smooth, this is because as You observed
$$F_y=1$$ for all points and because the function
$$\hat{f}(x)=\begin{cases}1,x=0\\ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\end{cases}$$
is smooth. To see that the first derivative exists use the rule of De L'Hospital twice:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,h\neq 0}\frac{\hat{f}(0)-\hat{f} (h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,h\neq 0}\frac{1-\frac{\sin(h)}{h}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,h\neq 0}\frac{h-\sin(h)}{h^2}\underbrace{=}_{De L'H}$$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,h\neq 0}\frac{1-\cos(h)}{2h}\underbrace{=}_{De L'H}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0,h\neq 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{2}=0.$$
So $$\hat{f}'(x)=\begin{cases}0,x=0\\\frac{\cos(x)x-\sin(x)}{x^2},x\neq 0\end{cases}.$$
Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)x-\sin(x)}{x^2}=0$. One would have to prove the existence of derivatives of any order to show smoothness. The latter essentially means that $x=0$ is a $\textbf{removable singularity}$ of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Now 
$$F_x(x_0,y_0)=\begin{cases}0,x=0\\-\frac{\cos(x)x-\sin(x)}{x^2},x\neq 0\end{cases}$$
implies $F_x(0,y_0)=0$ for every $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ but since $F_y(0,y_0)=1$ for all $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ none of these points ( in particular not $(0,1)$, which is the only one actually on the considered curve) is a [singular point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety) to the plane curve given by $F(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Correct me if I've misunderstood but: I was initially under the impression the point of defining 'removable singularities' is so that you can spot singularities you can remove from the function by defining them to be some value at those points and keep the function holomorphic. However, you seem to be suggesting we need to define the function at these points first before seeing if it's a removable singularity? But then once we've done that, they no longer are singularities??

Comment: From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableSingularity.html , the removable singularity would have to be a singularity in the first place before you remove it. Sorry if I'm slow to understand - I've just started Complex Functions and am still grasping these concepts.

Comment: The function is actually not defined at it's singularity, but if a continuously differentiable, smooth or even analytic function exists that continues the function in a neighborhood of this original singularity, it is a removable singularity and by changing to the continuation, You have removed the singularity, it is no singularity for the continuation, however this concept is different to that of a singular point on a curve, here singularity refers to the fact that if the partial derivatives vanish, there is no equation for the tangent

Comment: Ok, so I think that clears things up for me. A singularity is a point at which the function isn't defined (while a singular point of a curve is a point at which the partials vanish).

Comment: @Shuri2060 Exactly!!